# AWS: Re-use amazon Cognito Userpool in multiple serverless applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I have divided my serverless project in to multiple projects to avoid template error resource > 200. Now I am facing another error.

I have implemented authentication and authorization using AWS cognito which works well for lambda functions in one serverless application. I am trying to re-use same Cognito Userpool for authorizing API's in another serverless project. However, each serverless project creates UserPool again with same name in Cognito. How to avoid this issue.

Here is the how my serverless.yml and dummy response look like in lambda functions

```
CognitoUserPool:
  Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
  Properties:
    MfaConfiguration: OFF
    UserPoolName: userpool-impl
    #RequiredAttributes:
    #  - email
    UsernameAttributes:
      - email
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        MinimumLength: 8
        RequireLowercase: True
        RequireNumbers: True
        RequireSymbols: True
        RequireUppercase: True


CognitoUserPoolClient:
  Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient"
  Properties:
    ClientName: client-impl
    GenerateSecret: False
    UserPoolId:
      Ref: CognitoUserPool

ApiGatewayAuthorizer:
  DependsOn:
    - ApiGatewayRestApi
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
  Properties:
    Name: cognito-authorizer
    IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
    RestApiId:
      Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
    ProviderARNs:
      - Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoUserPool, Arn]
```

Lamdba function:

```
response = {
"statusCode": 200,
'headers': {
             "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
             "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True
        },

"body": "Dummy Response"
```

}

Comment: Don’t create the userpool in the new Serverless projects; it already exists. For your API gateway authorizer, in ProviderARNs put the ARN from the other project that you want to use. We do the same with our Serverless projects... Works perfectly.

Comment: You can use cross stack reference (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-reference-resource/). You can just reference existing user pool in other projects.

Comment: @hephalump can you help with configuration in serverless yml file how to do cross reference?